# Find & Replace Multiple Instagram Urls In A String Using C#

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I want to find all the instagram urls within a string, and replace them with the embed url.

But I'm keen on performance, as this could be 5 to 20 posts each anything up to 6000 characters with an unknown amount of instagram urls in which need converting.

Url examples (*Could be any of these in each string, so would need to match all*)

```
http://instagram.com/p/xPnQ1ZIY2W/?modal=true
http://instagram.com/p/xPnQ1ZIY2W/
http://instagr.am/p/xPnQ1ZIY2W/
```

And this is what I need to replace them with (An embedded version)

```
<img src="http://instagram.com/p/xPnQ1ZIY2W/media/?size=l" class="instagramimage" />
```

I was thinking about going for regex? But is this the quickest and most performant way of doing this?

Any examples greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"http://instagr\.?am(?:\.com)?/\S*");
```

Edited regex. However i would combine this with a stringreader and do it line by line. Then put the string (modified or not) into a stringbuilder:

```
string original = @"someotherText http://instagram.com/p/xPnQ1ZIY2W/?modal=true some other text
some other text http://instagram.com/p/xPnQ1ZIY2W/ some other text
some other text http://instagr.am/p/xPnQ1ZIY2W/ some other text";

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(original))
{
    while (reader.Peek() > 0)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (reg.IsMatch(line))
        {
            string url = reg.Match(line).ToString();
            result.AppendLine(reg.Replace(line,string.Format("<img src=\"{0}\" class=\"instagramimage\" />",url)));
        }
        else
        {
            result.AppendLine(line);
        }
   }
}

Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

You mean like this?

```
class Program
{
    private static Regex reg = new Regex(@"http://instagr\.?am(?:\.com)?/\S*", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    private static Regex idRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=p/).*?(?=/)",RegexOptions.Compiled);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string original = @"someotherText  http://instagram.com/p/xPnQ1ZIY2W/?modal=true some other text
some other text http://instagram.com/p/xPnQ1ZIY2W/ some other text
some other text http://instagr.am/p/xPnQ1ZIY2W/ some other text";

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(original))
        {
            while (reader.Peek() > 0)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                if (reg.IsMatch(line))
                {
                    string url = reg.Match(line).ToString();
                    result.AppendLine(reg.Replace(line, string.Format("<img src=\"http://instagram.com/p/{0}/media/?size=1\" class=\"instagramimage\" />", idRegex.Match(url).ToString())));
                }
                else
                {
                    result.AppendLine(line);
                }

            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());



    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think you have mis-understood the image with the class code example. That's what I need to get to from the urls. So I need to find all of the 3 urls within a string and replace them with the image.

Comment: if you can have 2 image urls in one line you cant do regex replacing. you need to iterate over the the matches and do simple string.replace.

Comment: and if you do this over and over again... for example dynamically i would use regexoptions.compiled

Comment: Hi Florian. Thanks again for your updated answer. To me, doesn't this just take the url and add it into the image tag? Problem is I think, is I need to pull out the id from the found url (In this case xPnQ1ZIY2W) and add that into the formatted img tag.

Comment: Well you can modify the string url as much as you like... Or am i loosing you alltogether?

Answer (score 0):

A well-crafted and compiled regular expression is hard to beat, especially since you're doing replacements, not just searching, but you should test to be sure.

*If* the Instagram URLs are *only* within HTML attributes, here's my first stab at a pattern to look for:

```
(?<=")(https?://instagr[^">]+)
```

(I added a check for https as well, which you didn't mention but I believe is supported by Instagram.)

Some false positives are theoretically possible, but it will perform better than pedantically matching every legal variation of an Instagram URL. (The ">" check is just in case the HTML is missing the end quote for some reason.)

Comment: Thanks for replying. The urls are likely to not be within Html attributes. Someone could just put in a plain text link. I need to be able to pick this up, and replace it with that image tag code example.